# How to send data gridview values from one page to another

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i want to send grid view data from one page to another without using database.
i am taking some inputs from user,  storing and displaying in gridview. now i want to send same data gridview values to another page on click of button.

what will be the best possible way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yous data not lives on GridView, but on the database, or on session, or on a file.

**The GridView only shows them, not store them** ! Even if you see them there, is actually on the html page on the client side, and they are not even post back.

So what you need to move to the next page is the "pointer" to the data, and reads them base on this "pointer"

You may have a simple `List<>` on the session, or an id and reads them from the database.
The solution is to saves your user input data somewhere - from what I understand the session for you can be a fast easy solution, and take them back on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

put the `gridview` data into `datatable`

then put the datatable into session as shown:

```
DataTable tb= new DataTable();
Session["dt"] = tb;
```

on the next page, to read session value:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable(); 
dt = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
```

to bind gridview data to datatable, check this link:

[Putting GridView data in a DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466487/putting-gridview-data-in-a-datatable)

hope it helped :)

Comment: is there any other way rather then using sessions?

Comment: no i think...sessions,cookies and querystring are the 3 ways to communicate betw pages...
for your probles session suits perfect solutions.