# save edited DataGridView to Datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I'm new to `DataGridView`
I want to create simple application that read `XML` to `dataGridview` Edit it than save it back to `XML`
My Problem is at the saving to DataSet/DataTable
this is my code :

```
    //I want to change column name than save it to file
    var column = DG_dataGridView.Columns[ColumnIndex];

    column.Name = ColumnName;
    column.HeaderText = ColumnName;

    string dataFile = "c:\test.xml"
    DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)DG_dataGridView.DataSource;

    dataTable.DataSet.WriteXml(dataFile);
```

when I view the `dataTable` object I see that none of my changes were set although I see the changes in `GUI` and `dataGridView` object

Comment: this is a winform app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember you're making changes in `GridView` not in `DataSource`. You will have to traverse the `GridView` and generate a new `DataTable`.

Create a separate function:

```
private void WriteToFile()
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

    //create columns
    for (int i = 0; i < DG_dataGridView.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add("column"+i.ToString());
    }

    //populate data
    foreach (GridViewRow row in DG_dataGridView.Rows)
    {
        DataRow dr = dataTable.NewRow();
        for(int j = 0; j < DG_dataGridView.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            dr["column" + j.ToString()] = row.Cells[j].Text;
        }

        dataTable.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    //write to file
    string dataFile = "c:\test.xml"
    dataTable.DataSet.WriteXml(dataFile);
}
```

and use it:

```
//I want to change column name than save it to file
var column = DG_dataGridView.Columns[ColumnIndex];

column.Name = ColumnName;
column.HeaderText = ColumnName;

//write to file
WriteToFile();
```

[Code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466487/putting-gridview-data-in-a-datatable)

Comment: I will approve this answer soon , but can you please incorporate / explain how can notify column order change into the code

Comment: Whatever changes you'll do in gridview, you will copy them into datatable so why need to worry about column order? It will also reflect off course.

Comment: No, asking questions is good. Never be in assumptions, always make yourself clear.