# Convert Grid view to Data Table

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I want to convert gridview data to data table. But my gridview has a lot of data and pageing is true on it. I should write this code (in this code first I load all data without paging):

```
 Cgv.PageIndex = 0;
 Cgv.AllowPaging = false;
 Cgv.DataBind();
```

then

```
 for (int num = 0; num < Cgv.Rows.Count; num++)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        ....//generate data table
  }
```

My data is lot and  **Cgv.DataBind()** is take time and at the end I get error.

Comment: This question is a copy of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466487
Next time search before you ask..

Comment: No. My data is lot and i have problem with  Cgv.DataBind(); but the loop for data table generation is yes and I found the loop in all search

Comment: I have  AllowPaging="True" in my gridview and  I have to first all data in my gridview again, this is take time a long

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("column"+i.ToString());
    }

foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        for(int j = 0;j<GridView1.Columns.Count;j++)
            {
                dr["column" + j.ToString()] = row.Cells[j].Text;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

please try this code